# textarea cols property when using CSS

Tags: xhtml, textarea

It seems that to be XHTML compliant an HTML textarea needs to have the cols property set.  I want to use CSS instead so I can just expand the textarea to 100% `style="width: 100%;"`

How should I be doing this in a standards compliant way?

Comment: Tom is right, it's good neighbor practice to accept one of the answers.

Answer (score 4):

I usually set a reasonable cols and rows amount, like 60 and 5. If you specify the width using CSS the cols and rows attributes don't have any function.

Answer (score 3):

Use both. That way, if CSS is disabled or not implemented on the target browser, it still works.

Answer (score -1):

No need to use css, there is an existing in line attribute for that known as `rows`.
just do this

```
<textarea type="text" rows="3" style="resize:none; " class="form-control" name="body"  required id="body" > hello</textarea>
```

now `rows` has from `"1" - "5"` and integer value will do real fine.

Comment: The question is asking how to use CSS to set the width as a percentage. Your answer tells them how to **not** use CSS to set the **height** as something that is **not** a percentage. That doesn't deal with their problem at all.